# Memory write in NIOS II - value put in wrong address

Tags: c, vhdl, i2c, nios

First of all, I should admit I have submitted this question on the altera forum (http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40494). I am asking here too because I think it is likely to be quite a different audience. If this duplicate post is against any stack overflow rules or etiquette please let me know and I'll remove it. If not i'll update the forum submission with any answers I receive here and vice versa.

I'm trying to integrate an I2C core from opencores to my Cyclone IV device. Apparently the version I'm using should just drop into the SOPC and work after being wired to some outputs ([alterawiki.com/wiki/I2C_(OpenCores)](http://alterawiki.com/wiki/I2C_%28OpenCores%29)). The core compiles with no errors or warnings.

The I2C docs with the core show 6 relevant registers addressed one after another (PRERlo, PRERhi, CTR, TXR, RXR, CR, SR). However, when I attempt to write to these registers the write is put into the wrong address whether from my code or manually in debug memory window.

To investigate this I set the registers to initial values in VHDL to see the result in the debug window. This showed that the register addresses for TXR and CR are not what is suggested in the docs.

```
Address   0  1  2  3 
09866160 AA 00 00 00 -- PRERlo
09866164 00 00 00 00 -- PRERhi
09866168 BB 00 00 00 -- CTR
0986616C DD 00 00 00 -- RXR
09866170 FA 00 00 00 -- SR
09866174 CC 00 00 00 -- TX
09866174 EE 00 00 00 -- CR
```

This would be fine, however, when I attempt to write to address 09866174 (TXR) the value is inserted at 09866164 (PRERhi). Similarly when I write to 09866178 (CR) the value is inserted into 09866168(CTR). This happens whether the write comes from the code or manually from the debug window. This is particularly confusing as writing to these registers works fine in VHDL.

```
#define IOWR(base,offset,value) __builtin_stwio ((unsigned int*)BASE + OFFSET, (DATA));
IOWR(I2C_MASTER_BASE, 5, 0x1D);
```

I have attempted to debug this from signal tap also. However, triggers on any of the registers are never implemented.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction here.

Thanks!

-update: I have been using the VHDL version of the core. However, I decided to throw in the towel for now and use the Verilog version which worked almost straight away when I wired it up. I intend to get back to the VHDL core when my application is done and will update this again then.

Comment: The code in the question looks as if you are #defining one macro and using a different one... can you explain a little more or pref post a more complete example? Also include what defines the address in hardware; i.e. the relevant bit of VHDL.

Comment: Apologies, I copied in the wrong #define. I know that my write works because for the first three registers I can write to them fine. The address of the I2C block is defined in SOPC builder. To be honest, as this is a 3rd party core, I havnt been able to figure out how the NIOS addresses for each register are defined. In the VHDL each register is just declared as a signal. I can certainly provide a large example of what I'm trying to do overall if that would help? Right now my main problem is why the writes could be re-addressed? Thanks for taking the time

Comment: ah, I think the offset value (5) may be rounded down to 4 if the NIOS is a word addressed machine. However you may want to address an offset of 5 *words* rather than 5 *bytes* in which case "char *" may not be the cast you want

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Sorry the "char" cast is part of the define I mistakenly copied in. I am actually casting to an unsigned int. So I think I am offsetting by 5 (32 bit) words. I have tried with a cast to char now too. The behaviour changes so that offsetting by 0,1,2 or 3 all overwrite the first address. Offsetting by 4,5 or 6 overwrite the fifth address. So based on where the VHDL initiated values show up I think you are right and I should be offsetting by words not bytes. Unfortunately it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: It also worries me that I cannot change the values in the addresses in question manually using the eclipse debugger (I can change the values in the addresses that work in the code). Reading from the addresses works fine, and it seems returns the value from the proper address in all cases.